# What is bus and interconnect error in mca?

Tags: mcelog

In Intel Mache-check error, the `MCA error code field [15:0]` in `IA32_MCi_STATUS` register, we see different error types, ex:

```
000F 0000 0000 11LL – Generic cache hierarchy errors.
000F 0000 0001 TTLL – TLB errors.
000F 0000 1MMM CCCC – Memory controller errors (Intel-only).
000F 0001 RRRR TTLL – Memory errors in the cache hierarchy.
000F 1PPT RRRR IILL – Bus and interconnect errors.
```

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1005184

I got an MCE error and it is `Bus and interconnect errors`, what is it? a PCI error? a memory error?